# Compare 'name' columns of two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, lookup

```
actual_df['new_col'] = np.where(lookup_df['name'].str.contains(actual_df['name'] + '-'), lookup_df['name'], 'Not Found')
```

The above code throws the following error:

> 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

How to do the required lookup with another data frame?

Comment: Please provide the proper code you have tried and the error traceback it throws.Also what output you desire?.

Comment: Thanks, I've provided the proper code and error which I tried. I need a new column in the actual dataframe by lookup the server names with string contains approach from lookup data frame.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? Reading your code it *seems* like you want to see where a name exists in another DataFrame's Series with the addition of a hyphen `-`

Comment: Yes, the other dataframe contains name-*, so I want to pull that to the actual data frame.. basically wildcard lookup from another data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "str.contains()" method, use slicing, if length of both columns are same.

```
actual_df['new_col']= np.where(lookup_df['name'] == actual_df["name"].str[:-1], df2['name2'], 'Not Found')
```

and if not, use "df.isin()" method of pandas :

```
actual_df['new_col'] = actual_df["name"][actual_df["name"].isin(lookup_df["name"].str[:-1])]
```

Comment: Thank you, tried this code. Its throwing 'ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects'

Comment: This is because, both the columns are of different length. Can you share a demo of both the columns and how you want to compare?